# Can an integral of a function that is not well behaved be finite?

Tags: definite-integrals, physics, mathematical-physics, elliptic-integrals

Consider the following integral which gives the time period of simple pendulum where $\theta_0$ is the initial inclination of pendulum with vertical.

T=$\sqrt{l/g}\int_0^{\theta_0}\dfrac{d\theta}{\sqrt{cos\theta-cos\theta_0}}$

As we can see the function is not well behaved at $\theta=\theta_0$

but rewriting the integral into elliptic integral (by making substitution $sin\zeta=\frac{sin\theta/2}{sin\theta_0/2}$) gives

T=$\sqrt{l/g}\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{d\zeta}{\sqrt{1-k^2sin^2\zeta}}$

which is well behaved.

As we all know time period of a simple pendulum is finite value. And intutively the first integral above should give a infinite value though the second integral solves the problem. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first integral does not give an infinite value, for the same reason that an infinite series can converge, or more to the point

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} =\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}} = 2 < \infty.$$

The integrand can have a singularity yet still be integrable.

Obviously this integral of $1/\sqrt{x}$ can be evaluated by finding the antiderivative and evaluating on an interval with an endpoint approaching the singular point in the limit.

For some more insight consider the improper integral of $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$ as a limit of right-hand Riemann sums for a uniform partition

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k/n}}\\&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}.\end{align}$$

Since

$$2(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})=\frac{2}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}} \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leqslant \frac{2}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1}}= 2(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1}),$$

we have

$$2(\sqrt{n+1} -1) \leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leqslant 2\sqrt{n},\\2(\sqrt{1+1/n} -1/\sqrt{n}) \leqslant \frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leqslant 2,$$

and using the squeeze principle

$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} =\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=2 .$$

We have a similar situation in your example.

**Perhaps a better analogy**

A change of variables can transform an improper integral into a proper integral.

Using the example $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{-1/2} \, dx$, change variables as $x = t^2$.

Then

$$\int_0^1 x^{-1/2} \, dx = \int_0^1 2 \, dt = 2.$$

Comment: Thank you .Your answer makes sense.But according to the definition given in spivaks calculus on manifolds, a function is integrable if it is bounded and sup(lower sum)=inf(upper sum).But the function above is not bounded.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes - if a function is unbounded then it is not properly Riemann integrable. That means the limit of a Riemann sum with an arbitrary choice of intermediate points will not converge.  However if the integrand is unbounded only at an endpoint of the interval, then it is integrable on any sub-interval and the limit as an endpoint of the sub-interval approaches the singular point may exist -- an improper integral. I was just trying to show that an improper integral can sometimes be evaluated as a limit of a specific Riemann sum as well.

Comment: Thank you for being of great help. I understand now

Comment: Actually there is a better analogy for your problem.  A change of variables can transform an improper integral into a proper one. For example, $\int_0^1x^{-1/2}dx$ becomes $\int_0^12dt$ using the change of variables $x = t^2$.